# Joins with multiple "." in tables

Tags: sql, join, teradata

Please excuse the backstory... I'm not very experienced with SQL, but I know a little more than "just enough to get myself into trouble". The knowledge I do have is built upon the experience I have with MySQL. One thing I haven't had much luck with is using any `join` (but I have been using every resource I can find to remedy this). Getting to it, I'm trying to do a `join` on two tables. I'm using SQL Workbench. The tables I have to work with seem a bit weird to me as depending on the query, I may or may not need to use a "." when calling it. Any time I try to `describe` any tables that I find from using `show tables;`, the query tends to fail unless I add "all_tables." (not the real name) in front of it. An example of this is `describe all_tables.sub_table_1;`. When running an actual query, only a handful of the tables require the "all_tables." prefix. Unfortunately, both of the tables I need to join require that prefix. So with all of this in mind, is there something special I need to do to `join` these tables? I've tried these things so far, but haven't had any luck:

````
select all_tables.sub_table_1.column_1 as "Code",
all_tables.sub_table_2.column_1 as "Name",
count(all_tables.sub_table_1.column_1) as "Count",
all_tables.sub_table_2.column_2 as "Description"
from all_tables.sub_table_1 as errors
left join all_tables.sub_table_2 as codes on errors.column_2=codes.column_3
and errors.column_3= codes.column_4
where errors.column_4 like 'floor_%' and errors.event_timestamp> timestamp '2019-09-30 00:00:00.000' and errors.column_5='9900' group by errors.column_1; ```
````

"[Teradata]Presto Query failed: line 1:8: Column 'all_tables.sub_table_1.column_1' cannot be resolved." is the output.

I realize that this is probably a semantics nightmare (quite possibly the syntax as well). I've tried removing the "all_tables." prefix, all of the `as` calls, and 4x checked the spelling, but the query always breaks in that same spot. Is my mistake something simple, or is there something more complicated going on here? Thank you in advance for your willingness to help after reading my novel.

Comment: Looks like you are using an alias on your table name: `from all_tables.sub_table_1 as errors` so try selecting the `alias.column_name`. For example, your first column would look like: `select errors.column_1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined aliases for your tables.  You need to use the aliases for *all* references:

```
select errors.column_1 as "Code", codes.column_1 as "Name",
       count(errors.column_1) as "Count",
       codes.column_2 as "Description"
from all_tables.sub_table_1 as errors left join
     all_tables.sub_table_2 as codes
     on errors.column_2 = codes.column_3 and
        errors.column_3 = codes.column_4
where errors.column_4 like 'floor_%' and
      errors.event_timestamp > timestamp '2019-09-30 00:00:00.000' and
      errors.column_5='9900'
group by errors.column_1, codes.column_1, codes.column_2
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the main problem. Now I just need to figure out the "must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause" complaint it's throwing at me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below, Aggregate issue should also be resolved.

```
select errors.column_1 as "Code",
codes.column_1 as "Name",
codes.column_2 as "Description",
count(errors.column_1) as "Count"
from all_tables.sub_table_1 as errors
left join all_tables.sub_table_2 as codes 
       on errors.column_2=codes.column_3
      and errors.column_3= codes.column_4
where errors.column_4 like 'floor_%' 
  and errors.event_timestamp> timestamp '2019-09-30 00:00:00.000' 
  and errors.column_5='9900' 
group by errors.column_1,codes.column_1,codes.column_2;
```